# Implementing a scrabble board

Tags: java

Suppose I have a class Square as follows:

```
class Square{
private String letter;
private boolean isfilled;
}
```

Now we know that there are 15x15 squares on a scrabble board. Can anyone help me with how to make up a scrabble board by using the Square class in the board class and also checking the constraints like if there is room to left or not or to the right?

Comment: Surely you have *some* ideas of how to start -- an array perhaps? Come on, give it a go. You'll probably surprise yourself with how much you can do. Then if still stuck, we can look at your code attempt and be in a much better position to give decent help.

Comment: you can use array : `Square[15][15] squares;`

Comment: Think in terms of objects and classes. You've already started off in the right direction with a `Square` class. What else can you think of that would be accurately represented within an OO design?

Perhaps a `GameBoard` class. Perhaps a `GameBoard` class composed into a `Scrabble` class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely familiar with the rules of Scrabble but given what you've mentioned, I would define a 2-dimensional array of Square instances.

```
private Square squares[][] = new Square[15][15];
```

You should probably instantiate these squares in your constructor.

Afterwards, you should provide an interface to set a value given some coordinates.

```
public void setSquare(int x, int y, String value)
```

Set this string to the specified square. Also you could make it so that if the string is empty or null (whichever you prefer), the square becomes 'unset.' This method should also validate the parameters if they are within bounds (within 0 - 14). You could also opt to implement that validation in another function such as:

```
public boolean isValidCoordinate(int x, int y)
```

So you won't encounter too much issues with going out of bounds of the valid set of indices for the array, you could define the board with a square buffer on all sides instead.

```
private Square squares[][] = new Square[17][17];
```

With this board, the only valid squares are from 1-16. Any x or y value with a 1 or 17 is invalid.

Personally, I would simply use Strings instead of defining an object Squares (if that's the only thing you're gonna do with them)

```
private String squares[][] = new String[17][17];
```

Null strings or empty strings, whichever, are unset. Otherwise, if you're going to implement any other method in the squares, then I guess defining a class for them is okay.